# XSRF check failed when sending POST to custom rest endpoint

Tags: html, forms, endpoint, jira-plugin, x-xsrf-token

I have a ScriptRunner Fragment which shows a form dialog. Here is the code:

```
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

showCloneEazyBIAccounts() { MultivaluedMap queryParams ->

def dialog =
    """<section role="dialog" id="sr-dialog" class="aui-layer aui-dialog2 aui-dialog2-medium" aria-hidden="true" data-aui-remove-on-hide="true">
        <header class="aui-dialog2-header">
            <h2 class="aui-dialog2-header-main">Clone EazyBI Accounts by Model</h2>
            <a class="aui-dialog2-header-close">
                <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-close-dialog">Close</span>
            </a>
        </header>
        <div class="aui-dialog2-content">
            <form class="aui" action="/rest/scriptrunner/latest/custom/cloneJE2Cube" method="post">
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label for="accountNames">Account Names <span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span></label>
                    <input class="text medium-field" type="text"id="accountNames" name="accountNames" placeholder="Cubo 1, Cubo 2...">
                </div>
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label for="projectKeys">Project Keys <span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span></label>
                    <input class="text medium-field" type="text"id="projectKeys" name="projectKeys" placeholder="JESC, JEBACK....">
                </div>
                <div class="field-group">
                    <label for="model">Model <span class="aui-icon icon-required"></span></label>
                    <select class="select" id="model" name="model">
                        <option>Select</option>
                        <option>JESC</option>
                        <option>JEBACK</option>
                        <option>COM</option>
                        <option>AGILE</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="buttons-container">
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <input class="button submit" type="submit" value="Clone" id="clone-button">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <footer class="aui-dialog2-footer">
             <div class="aui-dialog2-footer-hint"></div>
        </footer>
    </section>
    """

Response.ok().type(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).entity(dialog.toString()).build()
}
```

I need this form to send the data to another custom rest endpoint (that it works fine when i call it from postman), but when I submit this dialog, it appears "XSRF check failed".

Is there a way to make it work?

Best regards,
Eloi.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem sending the request with AJAX and adding headers: { 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck' }.

Hope this helps!

Comment: X-Atlassian-Token: no-check

Comment: If you are talking with an Atlassian product (JIRA, Bamboo etc.) you can disable XSRF protection in the administration menu (Administration / Security setting).

Answer (score 3):

It's because of headers that are added by your browser, In this case I think the problem is **User-Agent** header, override it to something dummy if it doen't solve the problem open networking tool of your browser and make override all custom headers which are added by your browser.

Comment: wtf, how on earth can this header cause such issue? Anyway, for others: there is an extension for chrome "**ModHeader**", add a request header "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0` and woala.

Comment: removing completely the header "user-agent" worked

Answer (score 1):

In our case, there were two possible solutions.

- Change User Agents Header (Not possible as far as I know in Chrome)
- Whitelist/Allowlist the origin domain in Jira. When you send a request to the Jira API your browser automatically populates the "origin" header. You need to add that value to the whitelist/allowlist in Jira. -> See here:
  https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver073/configuring-the-allowlist-1014667631.html
  Type "Domain" should work.

See the issue documented by Atlassian:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/rest-api-calls-with-a-browser-user-agent-header-may-fail-csrf-checks-802591455.html